How to prove the Hermiticity of the angular momentum operator's X-component?
I understand that the momentum operator is Hermitian (thanks to this proof), as demonstrated by verifying the inner product relation. However, I am unsure how to prove that the angular momentum operator, specifically its $L_x$ component, is Hermitian and thus observable.
The $L_x$ operator can be expressed as:
$$  
L_x = y p_z - z p_y,  
$$
where $p_z = -i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ and $p_y = -i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ are the momentum operators in the $z$- and $y$-directions, respectively.
Alternatively, in spherical coordinates, $L_x$ is expressed as:
$$  
L_x = -i\hbar \left( -\sin\phi \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} - \cos\phi \cot\theta \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi} \right).  
$$
To prove $L_x$ is Hermitian, I believe we need to check whether it satisfies the Hermitian condition:
$$  
\langle \psi_1 | L_x \psi_2 \rangle = \langle L_x \psi_1 | \psi_2 \rangle^*,  
$$
for arbitrary wavefunctions $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ in a suitable Hilbert space.
Attempting the proof:

I substitute $L_x$ into the inner product expression:
$$  
   \langle \psi_1 | L_x \psi_2 \rangle = \int \psi_1^* \, (y p_z - z p_y) \psi_2 \, dV.  
   $$

Compute the $y p_z$ and $z p_y$ terms explicitly:
$$  
   \langle \psi_1 | y p_z \psi_2 \rangle = \int \psi_1^* y \left( -i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \psi_2 \right) dV,  
   $$
$$  
   \langle \psi_1 | -z p_y \psi_2 \rangle = \int \psi_1^* \left( -z \left( -i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \psi_2 \right) \right) dV.  
   $$

Use integration by parts to see if the boundary terms vanish for well-behaved wavefunctions.


My questions:

Do both terms satisfy the Hermitian condition?
Is this enough to confirm that $L_x$ is Hermitian and thus observable?
Are there specific pitfalls in extending this analysis to spherical coordinates?

Could someone confirm if my approach is correct and point out any errors or assumptions I may have overlooked?


How to Prove the Hermiticity of the Angular Momentum Operator's X-Component?


I understand that the momentum operator is Hermitian...

I assume you also understand that the position operator is Hermitian.
I assume you also understand that the position and momentum obey canonical commutation relations:
$$
[r_i, p_j] = i\hbar \delta_{ij}\;,
$$
which means, for example, that
$$
y p_z = p_z y
$$
and
$$
z p_y = p_y z\;.
$$
I assume you also understand that if
$$
C = AB
$$
then
$$
C^\dagger = B^\dagger A^\dagger
$$
I assume you also understand that if
$$
D = A + B
$$
then
$$
D^\dagger = A^\dagger + B^\dagger
$$


The (L_x) operator can be expressed as:
$$  
L_x = y p_z - z p_y,  
$$

Thus, we have:
$$
L_x^\dagger = (y p_z)^\dagger - (z p_y)^\dagger
$$
$$
= p_z^\dagger y^\dagger - p_y^\dagger z^\dagger
$$
$$
=p_z y - p_y z
$$
$$
=y p_z - z p_y
$$


Do both terms satisfy the Hermitian condition?

Yes. For example, $(p_z y)^\dagger = p_z y$.

thank you so much!
